# I made a Bitcoin Core deposit and don't have a big enough HDD to download data

Tags: bitcoin-core

Wondering if anyone can help me. I downloaded bitcoin core (not realising you have to download all bitcoin data with it) and I am on a mac so I don't have enough disk space to complete the download (even if my disk was empty). I therefore have BTC in the account but will never be able to spend it, is there anything I can do?

Comment: next to the disk space and time required for the full node client, an option may be to extract the priv key from your core wallet, and bring it into Electrum (or similiar wallet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can buy a cheap USB 1Tb harddisk. Plug that in and then at startup elect to put the datadir (AND THE WALLET) on that.

If you do this and then send any coins make sure you backup the wallet.